# Помогите исправить ошибку в python

Tags: python, парсер, discord

Я пытался сделать парсер для дискорда, который бы выводил список участников дискорд сервера, точнее их id имеющие определённую роль
Ошибка выдается следующая:  "USER_TOKEN" is not defined

`USER_TOKEN` = это сам токен авторизации дискорда
`ROLE_ID` = id роли дискорда
`GUILD_ID` = id сервера дискорда

Я немного не понимаю как исправить код дабы он сработал.

Код ниже:

```
import requests
requests.get(
    f"https://discord.com/api/v9/guilds/{GUILD_ID}/roles/{ROLE_ID}/member-ids",
    headers={
        "Authorization": USER_TOKEN
    }
)
```

Comment: Вы пытались `"Authorization": f'Bearer {USER_TOKEN}'`?

Comment: Да, пытался , по прежнему та жа ошибка 
"user_id" is not defined